# Get Tabs to Appear Before Number in Multilevel Lists

Tags: microsoft-word, custom-multilevel-lists

I'm trying to create a new multi-level list that will put the tab character before the number and only a space after the number.  I can get only one space to appear after the number but no tab appears before any of the numbers (see image below).  I press the tab key and it indents the text but the tab character doesn't appear.

I need to export the file to a txt file that requires each line to have the number of tabs for that level.  For example, any text at level 2 should be preceded by one tab character and any text at level 3 should be preceded by two tabs characters.  I've provided a screenshot of what it currently looks like but I need the tabs to appear for each indent.

[image: Multilist indenting missing tab characters]

Answer (score 1):

1. In your document, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to insert a tab space, and then select and copy it.
2. On the **Home** tab of the ribbon, click **Multilevel List** > **Define New Multilevel List**.
3. Click **Set for All Levels**.
4. In the dialog box, set all the fields **0 pt**, and then click **OK**.
5. Under **Click level to modify**, select **1**.
6. Use the **Enter formatting for number** and **Number style for this level** fields to specify your preferred numbering format.
7. Click **More >>**.
8. In the **Follow number with** field, select **Space**.
9. Under **Click level to modify**, select the next list level.
10. Use the **Enter formatting for number** and **Number style for this level** fields to specify your preferred numbering format.
11. Put the cursor at the beginning of the **Enter formatting for number** field, and paste the tab space that you copied earlier.
12. In the **Follow number with** field to **Space**.
13. Repeat steps 9 through 12 for each additional list level, incrementing the number of tab spaces that you paste each time.
14. If your list items use the **List Paragraph** paragraph style, you may want to modify the tab settings for it, setting them at increments of your choice.

Comment: Thank you cnread!!!  Unfortunately, I'm getting an error when I try to paste in the tab character due to a Word add-in (I turned off the add-in but still get the error).  I'll need to try this on another PC this weekend.  Please let me know if I can somehow return the favor!